# What code coverage tool to use for the javascript code in a Kotlin Multiplatform project?

Tags: kotlin-js

I can use jacoco on the JVM side, but what can I use on the JS side of the Multiplatform project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now, there are no integrated code coverage tools.
But you can implement it manually using `karma.config.d` and https://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/config/coverage.html.

Note: you can do it only with `browser` target

How to setup:
Necessary to add dependencies, ideally dev dependencies into test source set, but dev dependencies are possible only since 1.4-M3, so they can be replaced with usual `npm`

```
implementation(devNpm("istanbul-instrumenter-loader", "3.0.1"))
implementation(devNpm("karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter", "3.0.3"))
```

After that create js file in karma.config.d folder in the project folder

```
;(function(config) { // just IIFE to protect local variabled
    const path = require("path") // native Node.JS module
    config.reporters.push("coverage-istanbul")
    config.plugins.push("karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter")
    config.webpack.module.rules.push(
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            use: {loader: 'istanbul-instrumenter-loader'},
            include: [path.resolve(__dirname, '../module-name/kotlin/')] // here is necessary to use module-name in `build/js/packages`
        }
    )
    config.coverageIstanbulReporter = {
        reports: ["html"]
    }
}(config));
```

It works with Kotlin code (but honestly report is arguable) but anyway, it provides both statistics for js and Kt files, but for js indicate 0%.

I created a feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-40460

Update:
The HTML file with results is in `build/js/packages/{$module-name}-test/coverage/index.html`. You can run `build` or `browserTest` task.

NOTE: If you on Windows you have to change `include: [path.resolve(__dirname, '../module-name/kotlin/')]` to `include: [path.resolve(__dirname, '..\\module-name\\kotlin\\')]`

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try this today.

Comment: how do you run / generate the reports?

Comment: Updated the answer. Also, see a sample project - https://github.com/ilgonmic/kotlin-js-test-coverage